# Can Goodstein's theorem be expressed as an axiom or axiom scheme in PA?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, peano-axioms

A statement like $\mathsf{Con(PA)}$ depends (or at least seems to depend) on a specific [Gödel numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering). My question is whether [Goodstein's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) may be expressed directly in the language of $\mathsf{PA}$, i.e. without relying on a Gödel numbering (or extending the language by additional predicates or by second order variables). Because the axiom of induction can only be expressed as an axiom scheme in $\mathsf{PA}$, I doubt that Goodstein's theorem can be expressed as a single axiom. But nothing seems to prevent an axiom scheme expressing Goodstein's theorem (especially if we don't care whether it is computable or not). Is there such an axiom scheme, and is this axiom scheme computable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goodstein's Theorem just says "for every number $n$" "there is a finite sequence $s$" "such that $s$ has some arithmetically definable property relative to $n$".

So the statement of the theorem can be written as a single arithmetical formula of the form $(\forall n)(\exists s)\Phi(n,s)$ where $\Phi$ is in the language of Peano arithmetic.

The only issue with stating this in PA is how to represent the sequence, but it is straightforward to state the theorem otherwise. Usually, sequences are represented using the method of Godel's $\beta$ lemma, but without any Godel numbering.

There's no need for an axiom scheme, and it is not clear how one would help.

Comment: Great, I know $\beta$-functions from lemma 10.6.11 in Ebbinghaus et. al. I will read it again now. An axiom scheme might replace $(\forall n)(\exists s)\Phi(n,s)$ with each specific instance of $(\exists s)\Phi(\mathbf{n},s)$ for $\mathbf{n}=0,S(0),S(S(0)), \ldots$. This helps if $\Phi(n,s)$ cannot be defined in PA, but $\Phi(\mathbf{n},s)$ can.

Comment: How an axiom scheme might really help here is by generating instances of $(\forall n)(\exists s)\Phi_\beta(n,s)$ for all (first-order PA) definable $\beta$-functions $\beta(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ (which can be proved in PA to be $\beta$-functions). This axiom scheme *might* be a stronger statement than an arbitrary individual instance of this scheme (also I don't know whether it *is really* stronger).

Comment: In the usual definitions of things, there is not a scheme of different $\beta$ functions - there is exactly one function which Godel names $\beta$ - see the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel's_β_function)

Comment: I tried to reflect on why I expected an axiom scheme, and my comment just tried to illustrate this with $\beta$-functions (motivated by lemma 10.6.11 in Ebbinghaus and how it presents these). There are more obvious encodings of zero sequences of natural numbers than specific simple $\beta$-functions. For example, a zero sequence $(a_n)_{n>0}$, which is zero for $n>k$, can be encoded as the number $z=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ (where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number). Because this encoding is computable, it can also be expressed by a first-order formula in PA.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "usual definition of things" regarding $\beta$-functions and Gödel's $\beta$-function. The wikipedia article refers to Mendelson 1997:186. In Gödel's 1931 article, in Hilfssatz 1 of Satz VII the same function as in the wikipedia article appears, but it is not named $\beta$. I don't have access to Mendelson, but lemma 10.6.11 in Ebbinghaus defines the two conditions that a $\beta$-function satisfies and states that such a function exists indeed. A footnote claims that the notation $\beta$ for such a function and the two conditions are due to Gödel.

Comment: To decode $z$ using a formula of Peano arithmetic, you would need to define something like "$a_i$ is the largest number such that this power of the $i$th prime divides $n$". Those definitions, in turn, require quantification over sequences, which requires some particular $\beta$ function to be defined at the beginning. This is the reason that the $\beta$ function is used in the first place, because PA does not otherwise have the ability to define things like the quoted property.

Comment: I think I can appreciate why Gödel needs a $\beta$-function to bootstrap everything. But the encoding of the sequence is not the only place where a $\beta$ function might implicitly be involved. The statement "such that $s$ has some arithmetically definable property relative to $n$" might also rely on "Satz VII" from Gödel's 1931 paper, and hence implicitly on a $\beta$-function. So a (non-computable?) axiom scheme expressing Goodstein's theorem could have instances for all $\Phi(n,s)$ which "provably" express Goodstein's theorem in the "intended" way.

Answer (score 1):

Carl Mummert stated

> There's no need for an axiom scheme, and it is not clear how one would help.

in his answer. The "reflected answer" given in the comment at least makes it perfectly clear why it is far from obvious that there's no need for an axiom scheme:

> How an axiom scheme might really help here is by generating instances of $(\forall n)(\exists s)\Phi \beta(n,s)$ for all (first-order PA) definable $\beta$-functions $\beta(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ (which can be proved in PA to be $\beta$-functions). This axiom scheme *might* be a stronger statement than an arbitrary individual instance of this scheme (also I don't know whether it is *really* stronger).

The replies to that comment got sidetracked by details about whether there is a single $\beta$-function, or whether a $\beta$-function just needs to satisfy the two conditions due to Gödel. But the important point is that there are many different encodings of zero sequences of natural numbers, and Goodstein's Theorem will make a statement about every formula expressing such an encoding. Different formula can express the same encoding, but PA "should be able" to prove that these formulas are equivalent. (In fact, I had some "known theorem" of this sort in mind when I wrote the comments, and mainly decided to write this answer when I noticed that I could no longer recall the details.) However, I can see no "obvious" reason why PA should be able to prove all instances of Goodstein's theorem for different encodings to be equivalent.

---

Carl Mummert stated that no Gödel numbering is required

> The only issue with stating this in PA is how to represent the sequence, but it is straightforward to state the theorem otherwise. Usually, sequences are represented using the method of Godel's $\beta$ lemma, but without any Godel numbering.

But "represent the sequence" is similar to a Gödel numbering in that there is no privileged canonical representation of the sequence, even if some representations are simpler than others.